# stripe subscription webhooks

Tags: .net, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am implementing subscriptions and I'm having troubles with the webhooks logic.

I create first an invoice item for the initial subscription which will be paid when subscribing like this :

```
var invoiceItem = await _invoiceItemRepo.CreateInitialSubscriptionPaymentAsync(product, stripeCustomer);
var plans = await _planRepo.GetAllPlansAsync();
await _subscriptionRepo.CreateSubscriptionAsync(stripeCustomer.Id, plans);

succesful case :
IiThenSub@su.su subscribed to Pro_Service 3 and 2 more…
IiThenSub@su.su was charged €3,000.00
IiThenSub@su.su's invoice for €3,000.00 was paid
IiThenSub@su.su has a new invoice for €3,000.00
IiThenSub@su.su's invoice item was added to an invoice
IiThenSub@su.su's details were updated
An invoice item for €3,000.00 was created for IiThenSub@su.su

Failed payment case:
IiThenSubFail@su.su's payment for €3,000.00 failed
IiThenSubFail@su.su's details were updated
An invoice item for €3,000.00 was created for IiThenSubFail@su.su
```

In the succesful case, I see that first the Invoice item is created, then added to an invoice, a charge is created, payment is succesful and subscription is done.

In the failed payment case however, I just receive an event with charge failed that doesn't contain the id of the invoice item, nor the id of an invoice.

So I have no idea how to link this failed charge to my subscription attempt. Could you point me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create the invoice item for the initial payment, 
then I manually create the invoice and pay it, 
once payment is received I create the subscription.
This way I do have an invoice and can receive the invoice.payment_failed event.
Only problem (negligeable in my case) is that it will create 2 invoices, the first one containing the invoice item, and a second one created automatically with the subscription, but with a 0 price so I just ignore it.

EDIT : event logs with this method

```
SubKo2@su.su subscribed to Pro_Service 3 and 2 more…
SubKo2@su.su's invoice for €0.00 was paid
SubKo2@su.su has a new invoice for €0.00
SubKo2@su.su's invoice has changed
SubKo2@su.su's invoice for €3,000.00 was paid
SubKo2@su.su's details were updated
SubKo2@su.su was charged €3,000.00
SubKo2@su.su's default payment source changed
SubKo2@su.su added a new payment source
SubKo2@su.su's invoice has changed
SubKo2@su.su's payment for an invoice for €3,000.00 failed
SubKo2@su.su's details were updated
SubKo2@su.su's invoice has changed
SubKo2@su.su's payment for €3,000.00 failed
SubKo2@su.su has a new invoice for €3,000.00
SubKo2@su.su's invoice item was added to an invoice
SubKo2@su.su's details were updated
An invoice item for €3,000.00 was created for SubKo2@su.su
SubKo2@su.su added a new payment source
SubKo2@su.su's details were updated
```

So I can now receive the events related to invoices and easily retry a failed payment

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because the subscription creation failed in that case. Since it failed, Stripe "rolls back" anything and won't create a Subscription and just returns an error. Because of this, it also will not create an Invoice so there's nothing to "map" to.

Unfortunately, the only way to map the `charge.failed` event to this event is based on the customer id and the fact that you just attempted to create a subscription which failed.